# How to build a graph from a dataframe ? (GraphX)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, graph, spark-graphx

I'm new to scala and spark and I need to build a graph from a dataframe. this is the structure of my dataframe where S and O are nodes and column P presents edges.

```
+---------------------------+---------------------+----------------------------+
|S                          |P                    |O                           |
+---------------------------+---------------------+----------------------------+
|http://website/Jimmy_Carter|http://web/name      |James Earl Carter           |
|http://website/Jimmy_Car   |http://web/country   |http://website/United_States|
|http://website/Jimmy_Car   |http://web/birthPlace|http://web/Georgia_(US)     |
+---------------------------+---------------------+----------------------------+
```

This is the code of the dataframe and I want to create a graph from the dataframe "dfA"

```
 val test = sc
     .textFile("testfile.ttl")
     .map(_.split(" "))
     .map(p => Triple(Try(p(0).toString()).toOption,
                      Try(p(1).toString()).toOption,
                      Try(p(2).toString()).toOption))
     .toDF()

  val url_regex = """^(?:"|<{1}\s?)(.*)(?:>(?:\s\.)?|,\s.*)$"""
  val dfA = test
      .withColumn("Subject", regexp_extract($"Subject", url_regex, 1))
      .withColumn("Predicate", regexp_extract($"Predicate", url_regex, 1))
      .withColumn("Object", regexp_extract($"Object", url_regex, 1))
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to take a look at the answer? Is it solving your problem?

Comment: Hi, yes the answer solved the problem. but I changed  ' val edges : RDD[Edge(VertexId, VertexId, String)] ' to ' val edges : RDD[Edge[String]] '. Thanks a lot !

Comment: And sorry for the late reply, I had issues and I wasn't able to verify the code. I did it today.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To create a `GraphX` graph, you need to extract the vertices from your dataframe and associate them to IDs. Then, you need to extract the edges (2-tuples of vertices + metadata) using these IDs. And all that needs to be in RDDs, not dataframes.

In other words, you need a `RDD[(VertexId, X)]` for vertices, and a `RDD[Edge(VertexId, VertexId, Y)]` where `X` is the vertex metadata and `Y` the edge metadata. Note that `VertexId` is just an alias for `Long`.

In your case, with "S" and "O" the vertex columns and "P" the edge column, it would go as follows.

```scala
// Let's create the vertex RDD.
val vertices : RDD[(VertexId, String)] = df
    .select(explode(array('S, 'O))) // S and O are the vertices
    .distinct // we remove duplicates
    .rdd.map(_.getAs[String](0)) // transform to RDD
    .zipWithIndex // associate a long index to each vertex
    .map(_.swap)

// Now let's define a vertex dataframe because joins are clearer in sparkSQL
val vertexDf = vertices.toDF("id", "node")

// And let's extract the edges and join their vertices with their respective IDs
val edges : RDD[Edge[String]] = df
    .join(vertexDf, df("S") === vertexDf("node")) // getting the IDs for "S"
    .select('P, 'O, 'id as 'idS)
    .join(vertexDf, df("O") === vertexDf("node")) // getting the IDs for "O"
    .rdd.map(row => // creating the edge using column "P" as metadata 
      Edge(row.getAs[Long]("idS"), row.getAs[Long]("id"), row.getAs[String]("P")))

// And finally
val graph = Graph(vertices, edges)
```

Comment: I have a node with multiple metadata can you help me create vertices RDD for the same ?

Comment: At least in Spark 3.4.x, it should be `Edge[String]` and not `Edge[(VertexId, VertexId, String)]`